# Delete mail from bash command line

Tags: bash, email, alpine-linux, mutt

I'm trying to find a way to delete a Gmail email using bash command line.

I tried to find something with mutt or alpine but I did not found a way to do it without launching the client.
The purpose is to delete the first email with one command line.

Comment: `telnet` or `openssl` could be used to do that. Related link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374737/bash-script-delete-mails-from-specific-address-pop3-account/40383017#40383017

Comment: Many thanks, your post lead me to the solution!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had few issue so I prefered imap connection this is how I did it and I empty all the mailbox as I don't need an email in once my robot read them. Thanks Aserre for your help :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 1

set ip "imap.gmail.com"
set socket "993"
set user "myusername"
set pass "mypassword"

spawn openssl s_client -connect $ip:$socket -crlf

expect -re ".OK.*" {send "01 LOGIN $user $pass \r"}
expect -re "01 OK.*" {send "02 SELECT INBOX\r"}

expect -re "02 OK.*" {send "03 STORE 1:* +FLAGS (\\Deleted)\r"}
expect -re "03 OK.*" {send "04 EXPUNGE\r"}
expect -re "04 OK.*" {send "05 LOGOUT\r"}
```

Bye

Comment: You should remove the space after `$pass` in `"01 LOGIN $user $pass \r"`, otherwise it doesn't work